# How to create Lexer/Parser?

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

Used:
Visual Studio - 2019

To install `ANTLR` I use - [tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs // Github.com](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs)

I took the grammar here - [antlr/grammars-v4 // Github.com](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csharp)
Grammar:
 - CSharpLexer.g4;
 - CSharpParser.g4;
 - CSharpPreprocessorParser.g4;

I did:
1. Installed ANTLR;
2. Created a WinFrom application;
3. Added grammar;
Right-click the project or folder in Solution Explorer and select
`Add` →`Existing Element`.

**Question.**
How to create Lexer/Parser?
The instructions say that additional classes should be created, but this does not happen.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

### Update 1.

I did:
1. I closed Visual Studio 2019;
2. I opened the project in Visual Studio 2017;
3. I deleted the files:
- CSharpLexer.g4;
- CSharpParser.g4;
- CSharpPreprocessorParser.g4;
4. I clicked "Add New Item";
5. I chose "ANTL 4 Lexer";
Note: there are no "ANTL" templates in "VS-2019".
6. I set the name to "CSharpLexer";
7. I clicked "Add";
8. Result:
- VS created a file - `CSharpLexer.g4`;
- VS created a file - `CSharpLexer.g4.cs`;
- VS for the file `CSharpLexer.g4` set the property" Action at assembly "=" Antlr4 ".

**Questions. Update-1.**
1. Am I right?
2. Where can I get data to fill out the file `CSharpLexer.g4`?
Can I take data from the file `CSharpLexer.g4`, which is located at the link
 https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csharp?
3. Do the files "CSharpParser.g4", "CSharpPreprocessorParser.g4" be created in the same way?
4. What template to use for the file - "CSharpPreprocessorParser.g4"?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you create a grammer file? once created and build the solution, your files will be created by ANTlr

Comment: @NirMH  ** 1. ** I downloaded the files `CSharpLexer.g4`,` CSharpParser.g4`, `CSharpPreprocessorParser.g4` from the link - [antlr / grammars-v4 // Github.com] (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csharp)
** 2. ** Added to the project `Right-click the project or folder in Solution Explorer and select
Add → Existing Element.`
** 3. ** Pressed `F6`.
**Question.**
Am I doing the right thing?

Comment: If you are already using VS2019, may I suggest you use my AntlrVSIX extension (following installation instructions), and just create an application from the Antlr template in the extension. Then after building, copy your grammar files to the project, and make sure the property for each .g4 is set to Antlr so that the Antlr tool runs on the grammar. If you want a library, go into properties of the project and change output type to a class library. Since the grammars contain embedded Java or C#, you'll have to pick Sam's copy or take the Java-based grammars and convert the Java code to C#.

Answer (score 1):

By adding the Antlr package into the VS project, including a grammer file and building the project, the output files (lexer/Parser) will be auto generated in the same folder the grammer file is located.

You should then use the VS "Add existing item" to add the generated cs files into your project so you can compile them as "C#" files.

Comment: Your offer doesn’t work for me.
  Updated the question. See "Update-1."
I would be grateful if you give your opinion on "Update-1".

Comment: I strongly suggest to read the Antlr4 documentation. basically you should define your language in Antlr "language" inside the .g4 files, then the tool will create an implementation of your lexer and parser inside the .cs files. you should not create your lexer by its own...

Answer (score 0):

If you failed to test with what @NirMH suggested, I strongly recommend you to **try with Java runtime firstly** as Java is the first-citizen in ANTLR project; https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/targets.md

Whatever target grammar you choose (in your case C#), to generate ANTLR4 result with Java runtime is stable than any other language. I've tested with JS, C#, and Python generator but all of them were not stable enough. The *stable* means, you might have an eternal loop during parsing in non-java ones.

Of course, you can parse `C#` file with the Java ANTLR runtime. To generate lexer/parser files, please walkthrough [the tutorial](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md#windows). The generated results are plain `.java` files, so you should create your own jar library file from them.

I agree that the entire process is not one-click-solves-all, but language treatment is always dirty.

To invoke `jar` in WinForm, you can use [IKVM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IKVM/8.1.5717) nuget package in order to convert `jar` to `dll` as below, and then add the `dll` into a WinForm project.

```
C:\ikvmc.exe -target:library csharp-lexer-parser.jar
```

Comment: Difficult ... I'll try to figure it out ...
  Updated the question. See "Update-1."
I would be grateful if you give your opinion on "Update-1".